# Does only multiprocessing or would multithreading of a single process also utilizes multi-cores?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

Would multithreading of a single process utilize multiple CPUs? Is it true in Python threading? Java threading? C++ threading?

Comment: It depends on how the host operating system schedules threads, and allocates them to available cores and CPUs.   It also depends on how the threading is implemented (e.g. how Python/Java/C++ runtimes deliberately manage allocation of threads, as distinct from just relying on the host to do it).    For C++, that is implementation-defined (e.g. the standard library from different vendors may do it differently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most languages (including Java and C++), each thread can run on a different core simultaneously, allowing (at least potentially) a significant speedup when running multiple threads on multicore hardware.

Python is a special case, however -- at least in [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) (which is the most common Python interpreter) there is a [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (aka GIL) that each Python thread must acquire before it can execute Python byte codes.  The GIL is necessary to keep the Python interpreter's state coherent, but this requirement means that even if you have multiple threads present in your Python process, only one of those threads will be executing instructions at any given instant, which means that your Python programs will not see any performance gain/speedup when running on multicore hardware.  The only work-arounds for that problem are:  use a different language, or use a different variant of Python, or spawn multiple Python processes instead (each Python process will get its own interpreter with its own private GIL and thus they can all execute in parallel).